# Creating multi-level navigation controller in xcode 4.5 using storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

I would like to have a menu like this:
A->B->C

A=> is a table view controller (Top level Menu)

B=> is also a table view controller

C=> UIView controller to display some details.

[image: Storyboard which I have now]

I was able to do till A in the storyboard which is shown by "Movie types". But how do I add the next table view controller ? I cannot just drag and drop another "Table view controller" and link it to the previous table view controller, right ? I am able to do it via code by pushing the next table view controller. But I want to learn it via Storyboard too. I am using Xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it in a storyboard, drag out your B view controller and connect A to B with a push segue.  Use the Attributes Inspector to give the push segue an identifier like `pushB`.

In your A view controller code, trigger the push segue using `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushB" sender:self]`.

Also in your A view controller, implement the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method to configure the new B view controller (accessible as `segue.destinationViewController`) based the  selected row in A's table.

You can then do the same things to connect B to C.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I do these things:
1. Drag a UIViewcontroller and embed in Navigation controller.
2. Have a segue between previous table view controller to my new navigation view controller, it crashes with:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
Do you know what I am doing wrong ? I know we cannot push navigation controller into another navigation view controller. But I do not know how to workaround it.

Comment: I didn't say anything about adding another navigation controller.  The push segue should be directly from your A view controller to your B view controller.